# how rubber keypad works

Tags: power-electronics, wireless, button, keyboard, keypad

Press on the keyboard, how does he connect the circuit of this key?
Two thin films, coated with conductive rubber circuit, with a thin film in the middle, with holes, used to isolate two thin films with conductive rubber.When the button is in the position of the hole, press the button, two thin films with conductive rubber pass through the middle round hole, and connect the circuit, which is encoded by the chip and output.

Comment: Is this a question? A question hoping for an answer? Or a question with an answer?

Comment: Can you rephrase this so that it is easy to see what you are asking? As you have a lot of words trying to describe the keyboard, wouldn't it be clearer as a diagram?

Comment: It would be good if you have a picture. As this doesn't sound like the typical rubber keypad I can think of

Comment: If you want to ask a question and also answer it, at least answer it in the answer section.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if if it answer the question but here is how rubber keypad typically work.

1. The rubber has a conductive pad attached to its underside; typically it's carbon
2. In the rest position, that pad is hovering over two copper pads on a PCB board. The copper pads have a small gap in between them
3. If you press down on the rubber the carbon pad comes down and touches both copper pads, making an electrical connection.